# JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an `ASP.net core` project that consume another `asp.net core API` project.

**Book class/Entity:**

```
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public virtual int AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Author   Author   { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

**API to be consumed:**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public List<Book> Get()
        {
        //This code will get all records from Books entity and load all related Authors and Categories records
            return _repo.GetAll<Book>(b=>b.Author,b=>b.Category);
        }
```

**Action who consume the API:**

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44356/api/");
    var response = await client.GetAsync("Values");
    var content  = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result   = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(content);

    return View(result);
```

**The problem:**

An error that told me this message:

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
> value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: Often that means you didn't actually receive json back from the api. It could be an html page depicting an error, or something else that isn't json. You can debug and review the value of the string before it is deserialized to see what it says.

Comment: Please note you should provide [MCVE] in the question - in particular if your question is about parsing JSON - show just `content` with inline value along with `Book` class and deserialization call, if your question is about why you are getting something else rather than JSON you still need to show result... but really no need to show the error. Please [edit] to clarify what you need help with.

Comment: ok how can I be sure that I sent this result list `return _repo.GetAll<Book>(b=>b.Author,b=>b.Category)` as Json ? and thanks

Comment: your `Get` should return `IActionResult` and the returned list should be passed in the method `Json(...)`. That's for sure to return a json. Otherwise, your client should include the accept header of `application/json`. As far as I remember, with your code, the list will be auto-wrapped in an `ObjectResult`, if not any content type inferred to get the exact `IOutputFormatter` to serialize the result, the first one that can serialize the data will be used, so it's possibly that the json serializer is used. To be sure, you can debug to see what `content` looks like (after fetching from your api)